# graphviz cluster top down

Tags: graphviz

```
digraph  {
    rankdir=LR
    compound=true
    node [shape="plaintext"];
    transfer->transferRead; transfer->transferWrite;
    transferRead->transferReadSendData[lhead=cluster_transferRead]
    subgraph cluster_transferRead{
        {
        rank=same;
        transferGetFile->transferSendType->transferReadSendData->transferRecvID;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

I want the cluster in the right，top to down。but get down to top。how to fix it？

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the edge direction in the graph **and** reverse the way they are displayed in the cluster:

```
    edge[dir=back];
    transferRecvID->transferReadSendData->transferSendType->transferGetFile
```